# Забрать текст из последних скобок в строке с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка: `Сочи (Адлер) (Россия)`, из которой мне нужно изъять текст, который находится в последих скобках. То есть, текст `Россия`. Для этого я написал регулярное выражение:

```
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)$/', ...);
```

Но оно почему-то выводит мне такие матчи:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "(Адлер) (Россия)"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "Адлер) (Россия"
}
```

Но почему? Ведь я поставил в конце `$`, что означает конец строки.

Comment: `.*\((.*?)\)$` - *почему...* - потому, что вы ищите от 1 открытой скобки до последней открытой скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подправьте шаблон, чтоб он искал НЕ скобки в конце строки:

```
$str = 'Сочи (Адлер) (Россия)';

preg_match('~\(([^()]+)\)$~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '(Россия)' (length=14)
  1 => string 'Россия' (length=12)
```

Comment: А если в строке после последней скобки будет стоять какой-либо символ или пробел?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie это наврятле, т.к. у ТС не зря стоит якорь `$`. Но если понадобится, то можно же дописать в шаблон необходимый символьный класс.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$/', 'Сочи (Адлер) (Россия)', $match);
print_r($match);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (Россия)
    [1] => Россия
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$re = '/(?!.*\()[а-я]+/iu';
$str = 'Сочи (Адлер) (Россия)';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Россия"
}
```

[Тест](https://ideone.com/fork/f2xfkd)